# SVG file flashing on page load before applying css styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an svg arrow icon on a page that is used to do a page jump to lower down on the page. The problem is that on page load the svg flashes quickly on the entire screen (as in full height and width) and then goes to the proper size and placement. I am hoping someone is able to help me with removing this or reducing the noticeability of it. I tried to initially put display: none; on it and then remove that class after 0.25 seconds with javascript but it did not solve the issue.

HTML:

```
<div class="intro-foot">
                    
                    <a href="#section-services" class="smooth-scroll delay-load">
                                             <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 64.57 80" class="smooth-scroll-arrow"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#fff;}</style></defs><title>Asset 6</title><g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2"></g></g></svg>
                    </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.delay-load {display: none !important;}

.smooth-scroll-arrow {
   margin-bottom: 70px;
   height: 30px;
   width: 30px;
   padding: 0px;
}

.intro-foot {
   -webkit-animation:bounce 2s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes intro-foot {
  0%       { bottom:5px; }
  25%, 75% { bottom:15px; }
  50%      { bottom:20px; }
  100%     {bottom:0;}
}
```

jQuery:

```
var $post = $(".smooth-scroll");
setTimeout(function(){
    $post.removeClass("delay-load");
}, 250);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be a few issues here, but let's address the lowest hanging fruit first.
First thing I would do is remove the CarouFredsel code since it doesn't seem to be necessary (only one element in the carousel?). That could definitely be messing with the sizing of the layout. After you do that, test again and see if it's fixed.